# Opening multiple tabs, attaching methods to them and having them run on the respective tabs

Tags: javascript

I am trying to figure out what's the problem with the code below: why does it work only for the first tab opened ? 
It throws an error on the 2nd attempt on tab being null.

```
for(let i = 1; i <= 3; i++) 
    setTimeout(function () {
       let tab = window.open('', '_blank');
       tab.document.write('argh'); 
    }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 2):

Browsers don't let pages open multiple windows in response to a single user event, since that's been abused repeatedly in the history of the web. Once you've created one, if you try to create another, the browser's popup blocker is likely to prevent it. You'll need to user to click repeatedly to open the windows (or do something else entirely).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Will look into the issue. Well... I guess I could still repeatedly append and remove a node which would serve as "the user clicking" ?

Comment: @Veverke- I don't know what you mean by "serve as 'the user clicking'", but the browser will be looking for an actual user click. That is, after all, the whole point.

Comment: This means there is no, whatsoever, workaround the issue, programatically ?

Comment: @Veverke - There have probably been several over the years, but when they're found and exploited, browsers fix them. Because they're bugs in the popup blocker.